# $p_n(z)=z^n$ is a smooth map on $S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, smooth-manifolds, spheres, stereographic-projections

I have to solve this one:

> Consider local coordinates on $S^n$ given by the atlas $\{(S^n\setminus\{N\},\varphi_N),(S^n\setminus\{S\},\varphi_S)\}$, where
>   $\varphi_N$ and $\varphi_S$ are the stereographic projection from the north and south pole respectively. Compute the expression in local coordinates of the function
>
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{array}{crcl}
> p_n: & S^1 & \rightarrow & S^1\\
>  & z & \mapsto & z^n
> \end{array}
> \end{equation}
>   with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and prove that is a smooth map.

Solution:

We can consider $z\in S^1$ as $e^{i\theta(z)}$, where $\theta$ is the angle function $\theta:U\subset S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $e^{i\theta(z)}=z$. According to this notation, we have $p_n(z)=e^{in\theta(z)}=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)$. Now we take $\varphi_N$ on $S^1\setminus\{N\}=S^1\setminus\{(0,i)\}$ and we get
\begin{equation}
\varphi_N\left(e^{in\theta(z)}\right)=\frac{\cos(n\theta)}{1-\sin(n\theta)}\ .
\end{equation}

So this is the expression in local coordinates (stereographics' one) and from it we see that $p_n$ is smooth.

Is it all right?

Thanks a lot